# directory folder name to put user defined packages in tomcat 7

Tags: java

I am new to java and jsp. I have just created a small package and that package contains a simple java class. Let me show what i really want to do. I am not working with servlets so please tell me about this simple example so that i can go ahead with my work. Below is my code or a package class and a jsp page.

**my java package**

```
package mypack;  //this is my package

public class Abc{
   public Abc(){
   }
   public void message(){
        System.out.println("My first java package");
   }
}
```

**index.jsp**     this is my jsp page where i need to use this package

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="mypack.*"%>
<%
 Abc a = new Abc();
 a.messsage();
%>
```

I was using JDK1.5 and tomcat 3. But i want to update my system. Now i have JDK1.7.0_11 and tomcat 7. I know the path of tomcat 3 to put my packages but i don't know where to put these packages in tomcat 7.

**tomcat 3 directory path to place packages:**

```
D:\Java\tomcat\examples\WEB-INF\classes   //i put my package at this path in tomcat3
```

**tomcat 7 directory path to place packages:**

```
D:\web\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF   //trying to put my package in here but no use.
```

I could not find the classes folder under the direcoty WEB-INF in tomcat 7. I made a folder myself named classes inside of WEB-INF but it does not work. Even i have deleted that my "classes folder" and put my package in WEB-INF, but it does not work. Please tell me the path where i can put my java package in tomcat server 7.

I have placed my jsp page in here:

```
D:\web\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\a    //folder "a" contains my jsp file. index.jsp and  
                                      its working
```

Problem is, jsp page could not find the package. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

packages are always located in  WEB-INF/classes, not directly in WEB-INF.
Try to put them here thus:

```
D:\web\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes
```